# Ошибка телеграм бота

Tags: python, telebot

ошибка -

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'
```

Как устранить ошибку?
C библиотеками telebot и  PyTelegramBotAPI  уже игралась (не помогло)

код

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalalal(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Попробуйте удалить и после поставить библиотеку. В консоли: `pip uninstall pyTelegramBotAPI` (проверьте, что после этого модуль будет недоступен, например запустив код, если модуль еще присутствует, значит что-то пошло не так), и поставить: `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`. А так, такая проблема встречалась тут https://github.com/MasterGroosha/telegram-tutorial/issues/9 и там помогла переустановка

Comment: тоже самое . я даже telebot  из библиотеке в самом pycharm удалила

Comment: теперь пишет такое ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'

Comment: Это правильная ошибка, ведь библиотека удалена, теперь установите `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI` и проверьте, должно сработать

Comment: теперь пишет delete the webhook first

Comment: Наверное, этому боту вебхук ставили ранее, посмотрите тут: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/139

Comment: да. спасибо ) я решила вопрос) удалила вебхук)

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Оформите сами ответ на вопрос :)

Answer (score 0):

нужно было зайти в pycharm ( я пользовалась pycharm) и там зайти в preferences(на маке)-projects->python interpreter( и проверить если там все нужные библиотеки). добавить, если нет telebot и pyTelegramBotAPI
. так же, что б решить вопрос с webhoo.можно было в предпоследней строчке кода добавить bot.remove_webhook()